# Structure of non-big divisors in an abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb{C}$. If $A$ has an effective non-big divisor, then $A$ is not simple. (In a simple abelian variety, every non-zero effective divisor is ample.)

What   can we say about the structure of effective non-big divisors in $A$?

Comment: On A we should have effective=>nef. Then the big cone equals the ample cone. And effective non big is the same as strictly nef. Any such divisor (at least if it’s a $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor) should be numerically equivalent to the pull back of an ample divisor from some quotient map of abelian varieties $A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: I think when you say "strictly nef" you really mean "nef but not ample".  "strictly nef" is actually a term of its own: it means $D \cdot C > 0$ for all curves $C$.

Comment: Can you expand on what you would like to know about "the structure of effective non-big divisors"? Yosemite Stan's comment gives one possible answer; is that the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: I was looking for what @YosemiteStan explained. Basically, from what I understand now,  non-big divisors are  pull-backs of ample divisors along some quotient map $A\to B$. Can you make this into an answer?